# Radio menu check

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, radio-group

Using Winform, is it possible to "radio check" a menu item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.radiocheck%28VS.80%29.aspx)

```
// This method is called from the constructor of the form to set up the menu items.
public void ConfigureMyMenus()
{
   /* Set all of these menu items to Radio-Button check marks so the user can see 
      that only one color can be selected at a time. */
   menuItemRed.RadioCheck = true;
   menuItemBlue.RadioCheck = true;
   menuItemGreen.RadioCheck = true;
}
```

Comment: MSDN Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.radiocheck(v=vs.90).aspx